# How do I deselect an active list item when I click on/activate another one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a simple, stateless parent component displaying a list stateful child components. Each individual child component represents a list item whose active state can be toggled (true/false). An active list item becomes green, with close (times) being displayed.

Now, my issue is when one item is selected (active) and I click on another item, both become active, as is expected. However, what I'd like is for the previous item to be deselected/deactivated, such that only one item can be active at a time. I tried lifting state up to the parent and passing it down as props, but this obviously results in every item being active when I click on one item. How do I achieve this?

Below are the code snippets.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ListItem extends Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false,
  };

  onToggleSelect = () =>
    this.setState({
      isActive: !this.state.isActive,
    });

  render() {
    return (
      <li
        style={{ color: this.state.isActive && "green", cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={this.onToggleSelect}
      >
        Item number {this.props.item}
        {this.state.isActive && <span>&times;</span>}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

function List({ itemList }) {
  return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            itemList.map(i => <ListItem key={i} item={i} />)
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
}

List.defaultProps = {
  itemList: [...Array(10).keys()].map(x => x + 1),
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd move the click handler up a level:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ListItem({ item, isActive, handleClick }) {
    return (
      <li
        style={{ color: isActive && "green", cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
      >
        Item number {item}
        {isActive && <span>&times;</span>}
      </li>
    );
}

function List({ itemList }) {
  const [activeListItem, setActiveListItem] = useState();

  const handleClick = (item) => activeListItem === item ? setActiveListItem() : setActiveListItem(item);

  return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            itemList.map(i => <ListItem key={i} item={i} handleClick={handleClick} isActive={activeListItem === item} />)
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, though this gets half of the job done. To achieve what I was looking for, you'd now simply tweak the handleClick handler such that if the clicked item is the same the activeListItem, set the activeListItem to be empty. Thanks, though, for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the state in the parent component to better manage the state of each item.

example with class component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ListItem extends Component {

  render() {
    const isActive = this.props.activeIndex === this.props.item;
    return (
      <li
        style={{ color: isActive && "green", cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={() => this.props.onToggleSelect(this.props.item)}
      >
        Item number {this.props.item}
        {isActive && <span>&times;</span>}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class List extends Component {
  state = {
    activeIndex: null,
  };

  onToggleSelect = (index) =>
    this.setState({
      activeIndex: index,
  });

  return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.props.itemList.map(i => (
                <ListItem
                  key={i}
                  activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
                  item={i}
                  onToggleSelect={onToggleSelect}
                />
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
}
```